# Issues implementing Slick Carousel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, slider, carousel

Newbie over here looking for some help.  I'm having trouble implementing the Slick carousel on my site.  I would like to use "Slider Syncing" found at http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Please see my code here: http://jsfiddle.net/g1xd6vtx/

The site I'm building is a C# .NET MVC4 project built in Visual Studio 2012.

Sample HTML:

```
<div class="slider slider-for">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
```

```
<div class="slider slider-nav">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
```

CSS (which I have placed in the head section):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick.css"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="slick/slick.min.js"></script>
```

Javascript (which I have placed in the scripts section):

```
$('.slider-for').slick({
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    arrows: false,
    fade: true,
    asNavFor: '.slider-nav'
});

$('.slider-nav').slick({
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    asNavFor: '.slider-for',
    dots: true,
    centerMode: true,
    focusOnSelect: true
 });
```

Thank you for any help! :)

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but this might help others:
I noticed that you have to have a block or inline-block element inside .slider-nav DIV. In this case I added an H1. Then style it to cover the parent DIV, then add text-align:center; to the parent DIV.

**CSS**

```
.slider-nav h1{
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
    height:80px;
}

.slider-nav .slick-slide{
    height:80px;
    color:#fff;
    background:green;
    cursor:pointer;
    text-align:center;
    margin:0 10px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="slider-nav">
    <div><h1>1</h1></div>
    <div><h1>2</h1></div>
    <div><h1>3</h1></div>
    <div><h1>4</h1></div>
    <div><h1>5</h1></div>
</div>
```

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/g1xd6vtx/2/